# The difference between `$/` and `local $/`

Tags: perl, variables, global-variables, temp

For my program, I need to use FASTA files and do some calculations with them. In order to do that, I used `local $/ = "^>`, to chomp up my file in to header line and sequence lines. While my program does what I want it to do, why can't I just simply use `$/ = "^>"`? When I tried it, my results were not what I needed, I'm interested why is that so. Here's my simplified code:

```perl
my @array;
while(<>){
    local $/ = "^>";
    chomp;
    push (@array, $_);
    if(eof){
        for(@array){
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
    if(eof){
        @array = ();
    }
```

Comment: [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): "Remember: the value of $/ is a string, not a regex. awk has to be better for something. :-)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`local $var` saves the value of `$var`, and adds a directive to the stack that will cause the value of `$var` to be restored when the scope is exited (even by exception). It's the closest thing to `my` that's available to package variables.

```
$_ = 123;
{
   local $_ = 456;
   # $_ is 456 here.
}
# $_ is back to being 123 here.
```

This is useful to avoid causing problems in surrounding code or in the caller (in the case of subs).

Note that value of `$/` is matched character-for-character. It's not treated as a regular expression.

Note that `$/` appears to be set for no reason in the code you posted (unless you left something out).

---

> *why can't I just simply use `$/ = "^>"`*

Then, the change wouldn't be undone at the end of the block, so it would affect the `<>` in the `while` condition as well as any code after your loop that performs reads.

---

How I'd handle a FASTA file:

```
my ($header, $seq);
while (1) {
   my $line = <>;
   if (!defined($line) || $line =~ /^>/) {
      work($header, $seq) if defined($header);

      last if !defined($line);

      chomp($line);
      $header = substr($line, 1);
      $seq = "";
   } else {
      chomp($line);
      $seq .= $line;
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, your answer really helped. I left all of the calculations out, but they are the reason why I set `$/`.

Comment: `$/` is only used by `readline` (aka `<>`, `<FH>` and `<$fh>`), not by calculations.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But to do these calculations I need to process my file in order to do them

Comment: I've made an addition to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html)

> modifies the listed variables to be local to the enclosing block, file, or eval.

It saves away the value of an (already existing) variable, which can then be changed as desired and still once the scope is exited its original value is restored.

As such it is used precisely with the global variables like `$/` -- by `local`-izing them we can alter their value within the scope where we need it and not have it change for the whole program.

More is provided [in perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local()).

What is shown raises questions though. The [`$/` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/) takes a string, not a regex; from what I recall those "fasta" files have lines starting with `>`, not with `^>`. Also, `$/` need be set before reading lines (with `<>`) and I don't see how the shown code does what its intent is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code relies on undefined behavior:

- to quote from [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> Remember: the value of `$/` is a string, not a regex. **awk** has to be better for something. :-)

- you modify the value of `$/` **inside** the `while (<>)` which is supposed to affect it.

Correct would be:

```perl
my @array;
{
    local $/ = ">";
    while (<>) {
        ...
    }
}
```

then the observed difference simply disappears, i.e. the code behaves the same with or without `local`.

But you should always use `local` on global variables to ensure that the original value is restored when leaving the scope of the `local` definition.

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour being invoked.

Comment: `local $/ = "\n>";` would be more in line with the intent